# Matplotlib Horizontal Bars: Value Error

Tags: python, matplotlib

For some reason, whenever I run the code below I get a Value Error: Could not convert string to float: 'A'

I change a comma to a decimal point below so the lengths line up between axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12,9))

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

x_axis = 8.6667, 9.5, -8.4, 0, -4, 6
y_axis = 'A','B','C','D','E','F'
ind = np.arange(len(y_axis))

plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(ind, y_axis, fontsize=14)
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',
    which='both',
    top='off')

plt.tick_params(
    axis='y',
    which='both',
    right='off',
    left='off')

plt.title('Super Awesome Title', fontsize=18, ha='center')

for a, b in zip(y_axis, ind):
    plt.text(a, b, str(a), fontsize=16, color='black')

plt.barh(ind, x_axis)
```

Comment: you can't plot letters...?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  Also, which line is throwing the error?

Comment: You code here doesn't run because `len(x_axis)=7`, but `len(y_axis)=6`

Comment: I'm using version 3.4.  It does not specify the line throwing the error. I thought it was the "barh =..." line but I modeled this after the example on the Matplotlib site (for horizontal bars):http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html

Comment: I corrected the numbers for x_axis but received the same error.

Comment: It looks like it might be an issue with "for a, b in zip..."